# Tensorflow Lite model not detecting objects and crashing sometimes

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

System information
**OS Platform and Distribution **:Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10
TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): binary
TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.9.0 CPU
Bazel version (if compiling from source): 0.11.1

Hello, I followed the following [steps](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) for training my tensorflow model ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco (the tf records and env preparations were done using this [tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) )

All this was done on windows 10, the model works fine, even on the Tensorflow Android App
then for exporting to TF lite format i i sent the .pb file to a Ubuntu dist and the FLOAT command [used](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md)

My issue arise when I try to run the model on the tensorflow lite android app, I followed the instructions that are [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md) to add a custom model, but my model doesn't detect anything. When I try to press the volume down button to "debug" the inferences the app crashes. This is my relevante android stack:

`03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.tensorflow.lite.demo, PID: 30807 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.tensorflow.demo.Classifier.enableStatLogging(boolean)' on a null object reference 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at org.tensorflow.demo.DetectorActivity.onSetDebug(DetectorActivity.java:294) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraActivity.onKeyDown(CameraActivity.java:420) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2712) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3291) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:383) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4767) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4639) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4181) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4234) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4200) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4327) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4208) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4384) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4181) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4234) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4200) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4208) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4181) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4234) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4200) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4360) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4521) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2435) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1998) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1989) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2412) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 3080`7 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 03-09 19:22:19.311 u0_a4 30807 30807 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)`

Comment: This is likely an issue with detector creation, which could occur if the model cannot be found or loaded properly. You should take a look at the `adb logcat` to see if there are any related errors being logged the console.